# SignalR Client to MVC5

Tags: c#, client-server, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr-hub

I'm trying to hit my MVC5 SignalR Hub via a separate, tiny client application, to no avail.

Some background:

I have a regular ASP.NET application using SingalR 1.10, that I can hit with my client. Code:

ASP.NET Hub:

```
namespace SignalrTest
{
    public class ScanHub : Hub
    {
        public void SendScan(string data, string xmlData)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(data, xmlData);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
 connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:2446/");
 hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("ScanHub");
 connection.Start();

 ........

 private static async Task RunAsync()
 {
     object[] param = new object[2];
     param[0] = _Data;
     param[1] = _xmlData;
     await hubProxy.Invoke("SendScan", param);
 }
```

and again, that's working fine.  My MVC Hub is identical to the other (I've made sure to change the client HubConnection address), and I have my Startup.cs as:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SignalrTest.Startup))]
namespace SignalrTest
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

running my client, it fires off with no errors, but I get no response or any indication that anything has occurred on the MVC side.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with the MVC app?  I'm unclear on whether I need to alter the routing.  I'm happy to post any other code that would help resolve my issue.  Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing your connection on the .NET client into an async method like so and doing a quick test if your connection is good or not.

```
 private async void Connect()
 {
   connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:2446/");
   hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("ScanHub");
   await connection.Start();
   //If using WPF you can test like so if not use whatever output method you prefer to see if it connects
   if (Connection.State == Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connected)
   {
            MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
   }
   else
   {
            MessageBox.Show("Fail!");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using SignalR 1.1? SignalR 1.1 doesn't use OWIN startup classes, and the MapSignalR method shouldn't even compile.